# What happens when the following code runs?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char a, b, c;
    scanf("%2c%2c",&a, &b);
    printf("%c%c",a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter "asdfghj" it will output "fd",but not "ad"

Comment: `a` and `b` can only hold 1 character each.

Comment: *"What happens when the following code runs?"* - madness  ensues. This code invokes undefined behavior. You're trying to stuff 2lbs of chars in a 1lb bag.... twice.

Comment: The argument corresponding to `%2c` needs to be a pointer to an array with at least 2 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of your code is undefined, which means that it can have different results depending on which compiler you use and which machine you run the resulting executable on.

One possibility that would have the results you've observed is that the compiler stores `a` and `b` on the stack, allocating space for each to hold exactly one `char`. This results in a layout like this (assuming a `char` is one byte):

```
==========================================================================
| Memory Address | Variable | Value after   | Value after   | End result |
| (byte)         |          | assignment to | assignment to |            |
|                |          | `a`           | `b`           |            |
==========================================================================
| 128            |          | s             | s             | s          |
| 127            | a        | a             | f             | f          |
| 126            | b        | ?             | d             | d          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On x86, the stack grows downward (from higher addresses to lower addresses), so this could very well be what you are observing.

But remember, **you should not rely on this behavior, as it is not guaranteed to work the same way in all circumstances.**

Comment: nice explanation